# Select an input from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have these two rows:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="numart" id="numart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="descart" id="descart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="pdepart" id="pdepart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="pvart" id="pvart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="ageart" id="ageart"/></td>
  <td><a class="plus" title="Rajouter une ligne">+</a></td>
</tr>
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="numart" id="numart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="descart" id="descart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="pdepart" id="pdepart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="pvart" id="pvart"/></td>
  <td class="contenu"><input type="text" name="ageart" id="ageart"/></td>
  <td><a class="plus" title="Rajouter une ligne">+</a></td>
</tr>
```

How would I select:

```
<input type="text" name="pvart" id="pvart"/>
```

From:

```
<input type="text" name="pdepart" id="pdepart"/>
```

Because:

```
pvart= 2*pdepart
```

Comment: Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: What do you mean by select?  Do you mean "pre-populate" or something else?

Comment: your code seems id duplication, which is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should resolve the duplicated ids to avoid problems with JavaScript

if you just want to react on changes in one input, multiply it with two and then insert into the other input then you can do something like:

```
$("#pdepart").change(function() {
    $("#pvart").val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * 2);
});
```

EDIT: if you only want to do it once:

```
 $("#pvart").val(parseInt($("#pdepart").val(), 10) * 2);
```

Comment: i   would   to  select $("#pvart")  on the same line  with  $("#pdepart")

Comment: sorry I do not get it... what do you mean by "the same line"? the code example shows how to react on changes...

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your answer to be correct HTML.  HTML does not allow two elements with the same id attribute.  If this is how yours page is coded then you need to fix this problem first.

If you want to pre-populate then use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line of code on event when you think its correct to populate `pvart`.
Probably onkeyup event of `pdepart` or onblur event of `pdepart`
Added `+` icon to convert the value into the number

```
document.getElementById('pvart').value = (+document.getElementById('pdepart').value)*2;
```

Comment: i would like to select $("#pvart") on the same line with $("#pdepart")

Comment: unable to understand on the same line.
by same line do you mean the `pvart` and `pdepart` in same TDs

Comment: another example of having it reversed when you edit pdepart `var el1 = document.getElementById('pvart');
   var el2 = document.getElementById('pdepart');
   el1.onkeyup = function(){
    el2.value = (+el1.value)*2; 
   };
   el2.onkeyup = function(){
    el1.value = (+el2.value)/2; 
   };`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pdepart').each(function() {
   if(this.value)
       $(this).next('#pvart').val(parseInt(this.value) * 2);
});
```

OR, if you want to change any event then can do following:

```
$('#pdepart').on('keyup', function() { //  you can bind any event like focus, change, blur etc
   if(this.value)
           $(this).next('#pvart').val(parseInt(this.value) * 2);
});
```

***NOTE:***

`$(this).next('#pvart')` will select the `input#pvart` next to `input#pdepart` you are handling.